# Java reflection CAP#1 casting error

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I'm working on a java project, this is my code:

```
Class<? extends Component> componentClass = componentField.getType();
Component tempComponent = entity.get(componentClass);
```

This is my error:

```
incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Component> where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

componentField is a field from which I know that it extends Component, when I try to get the type it returns me a fresh-type CAP#1, is it possible to cast it to a class extending from component? the entity.get() is a generic method that takes a `<T extends Component>` as argument.

Comment: `componentField.getType()` probably returns `Class<?>` and not `Class<? extends Component>`

Comment: I know it returns class<?>, the question is if I can get the real class to be returned because I need to give it along the .get() method.

Comment: You'd have to cast it, probably via the raw type: `(Class) componentField.getType()`, and add @SuppressWarnings as appropriate.

Comment: If `entity` is a `Map`, then it won't care what type you give to its `get()` function. You might just be able to skip the casting altogether.

Answer (score 0):

What will be difference? it is

```
 Class<?> or Class<? extends Component>
```

if you want to check Class is extendeding Component .. why not using `Class#isAssignableFrom(Class type)`

```
Class componentClass = componentField.getType(); 
if(componentClass != Component.Class && Component.isAssignableFrom(componentClass){
 Component tempComp = entity.get(componentClass);
}
```